# PyQGIS changing basemap crs when importing a csv

Tags: python, csv, mapping, gis

I am using PyQGIS to import a csv file with a lat and long, when doing this I am using the appropriate crs of EPSG:4326.
I'm plotting this onto Google Maps.

I load my basemap, then import my CSV. The issue is that my basemap projection then changes to 4326 and I need it to remain on 3857.

I've tried importing the basemap after the CSV and moving it down in the layers, however this still changes the projections.

```
import requests
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis import core

#Use Google Street Map as QGIS basemap.
service_url = "mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}" 
service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url=https://"+requests.utils.quote(service_url)
tms_layer = iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "GoogleSat", "wms")

#Import CSV and plot.
uri = 'file:///home/user/fred.csv?type=csv&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s' % ("Site Longitude", "Site Latitude", "EPSG:4326")
layer_csv = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'fred', 'delimitedtext')
layer_csv.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_csv)
```

I'll be the first to admit I'm a novice with QGIS!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has something to do with the application not refreshing properly as mentioned in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273252/qgis-changing-canvas-crs-defaults-to-imported-layer) on gis stack. You may want to look into it for details.

To answer your question in brief, you can add `QApplication.instance().processEvents()` after `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer_csv)` and then use `setCrs()` to set your basemap CRS to whatever value you need. It will hold.

```
proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.addMapLayer(layer_csv)

# This line makes the difference
QApplication.instance().processEvents()

# This sets the project CRS back to 3857
proj.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857))
```